# Where is sql server reporting service virtual folder hosted?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I installed the SSRS 2012 and tried visit 
http://mybox.org/Reports, but get an error saying:

> User 'mybox\xxx' does not have required permissions. Verify that
>   sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account
>   Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed

So I tried to check the IIS settings. But astonishingly found that in my IIS 8 management console, there's no Reports site or virtual folder. So, where is the Reports being hosted? And how to troubleshoot this permission error?

Answer (score 11):

Physical directory of reportserver and report manager can be found under:

`\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services`

Comment: Thank you. Following the pattern, mine was in MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER for SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 5):

[SSRS 2008 doesn't need IIS to work anymore.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630449%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) It sounds like that error is coming straight from SSRS and not the web server anyway. You need to give your account (MYBOX\xxx) access using the report manager interface. (SSMS can no longer be used to grant rights for report manager).

You'll need local administrator access to the machine that SSRS is installed on since it automatically has system-wide admin rights in report manager. Then you just navigate to `http://localhost/reports` and give \MYBOX\xxx whatever security permissions you need.

[An MSDN tutorial on user rights management in SSRS.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/aa337491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. That tutorial is for 2008 R2, but I am using SSRS 2012. And I cannot even open the http://mybox.org/ReportServer, but the tutorial needs me to click the 'site settings' on that page.

Comment: and btw, do you know where the ReportServer virtual folder is physically located?

Comment: If SSRS is running on your computer try using localhost instead of mybox.org. The location of the folder on your hard drive that contains the files for report manager depends on your SQL server installation. Just do a file search for a folder named "ReportManager" it should be somewhere under the SQL server folder in program files. (I've only checked on a 2008 R2 server. I don't have access to a SQL 2012 server.)

Comment: I tried "dir ReportServer /s" "dir Reports /s" on all my disks, found nothing. That's why I am confused. Also, I have tried localhost. (The mybox.com is just a placeholder because stackoverflow doesn't allow an URL contains localhost.)

Comment: Report manager's default location isn't at http://server/ReportServer, try using /Reports and see if it loads up. Also make sure you're running the browser as administrator so that you'll login as that.

Comment: Also the folder is named ReportManager and not ReportServer.

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server 2017** the location pattern changed and now the *default* physical directory of `ReportServer` is:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer`